# MooTools: JSON.encode and Request.JSON shows no POST data

Tags: json, post, mootools

I have the following Request.JSON in my clientside (notice the conversion to a JSON string with MooTools' own JSON parser):

```
var data = {action: 'delete', data: { id: item} };
data = JSON.encode(data);

var aRequest = new Request.JSON({
                onSuccess : (function(json) {
                    ...
                }).bind(this),
                onFailure : (function(e) {
                    ...
                }).bind(this),
                onError : (function(text, error) {
                    ...
                }).bind(this),
                url : "../sd_delete.php",
                method : "post",
                data: data,
                urlEncoded: false
            });
    aRequest.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    aRequest.send();
```

Now, on the server side, both $_REQUEST and $_POST are empty arrays. How do I access the string I sent with Request.JSON? Or is there something flawed in my clientside approach?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Just found out that, even if I send the data as an object (without JSON.encode), there is no POST data on the server side. GET works. Might be a serverside problem?!

Comment: is it a restful server? perhaps your content type definition is being rejected if it's not and it expects formdata instead? php usually works with the latter...

Comment: that might be the case - it's not a restful server. although, when I removed the setHeader() call, it wouldn't work either. where do I lookup the settings for that kind of stuff on an Apache server?

Comment: urEncoded then also needs to be true (default). data needs to be a simple object which it will convert to a collection for $_REQUEST that php can work with. in general. Request.JSON makes sense for reading data but for sending, unless you are on a rest backend, use formencoded.

Comment: That did it. Apparently, it is impossible to send a JSON-encoded string with POST to a non-restful backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work.

```
var data = {action: 'delete', data: { id: item} };

var aRequest = new Request.JSON({
    url : "../sd_delete.php",
    onComplete: function(pResponse) {
        console.log(pResponse);
    }.bind(this)
}).post(data);
```

You'll then receive post data as following in php:

```
echo $_POST['action'];
```

Answer (score 2):

`data` option should be an object. Try:

```
        new Request.JSON({
            onSuccess : (function(json) {
                ...
            }).bind(this),
            onFailure : (function(e) {
                ...
            }).bind(this),
            onError : (function(text, error) {
                ...
            }).bind(this),
            url : "../sd_delete.php",
            method : "post",
            data: { anyname: data },
            urlEncoded: false
        });
```

Comment: yep. other than that, seems ok.

Comment: That doesn't work, print_r($_REQUEST) gives an empty array. The request payload as shown in Chrome Web Developer gives: data=%7B%22action%22%3A%22delete%22%2C%22data%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A3%7D%7D for the JSON "{"action":"delete", "data":{"id":3}}"